# Curl work in php-cli and cli, but not work in php

Tags: php, linux, curl

I'm on Linux Fedora 20, with a LAMP.
I use this simple php script which use curl :

```
// test.php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/file.xml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, FEDORA_USER.":".FEDORA_PASS);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

In php cli, I make :

> php test.php
>
> Curl works.

In php cli, I make :

> curl http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/file.xml
>
> Curl works.

But in a navigator (chrome, firefox, ...), curl doesn't work. The error is :

```
Fatal error: (7) `curl_exec(...)` returned false. 
Error: Failed to connect to xx.xx.xx.xx: Permission denied. 

Info: Array ( [url] => http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/file.xml 
              [content_type] => 
              [http_code] => 0 
              [header_size] => 0 
              [request_size] => 0 
              [filetime] => -1 
              [ssl_verify_result] => 0 
              [redirect_count] => 0 
              [total_time] => 0 
              [namelookup_time] => 1.6E-5 
              [connect_time] => 0 
              [pretransfer_time] => 0 
              [size_upload] => 0 
              [size_download] => 0 
              [speed_download] => 0 
              [speed_upload] => 0 
              [download_content_length] => -1 
              [upload_content_length] => -1 
              [starttransfer_time] => 0 
              [redirect_time] => 0 
              [redirect_url] => 
              [primary_ip] => 172.17.100.8 
              [certinfo] => Array ( ) 
              [primary_port] => 8080 
              [local_ip] => 
              [local_port] => 0 
            ) 
in /home/...../test.php on line 139
```

Navigator use /etc/php.ini

Php-cli use /etc/php.ini

I don't unterstand why it doesn't work on navigator, the problem isn't server side. Can you help me?

Comment: I assume you have checked that the `php_curl` and `php_openssl`  extensions are enabled in the php.ini used by Apache? Its not the same one that is used by PHP CLI in most cases, although I am not a fedora user.

Comment: Yes, they are enabled in phpinfo().

Comment: Maybe you have disabled php-curl mod in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini. 
php-cli and apache2 php.ini - is different files.

Comment: Also possible, that remote host reject your http-query. Try to execute also file_get_contents('http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/file.xml'). If it gives you same result, its not a curl problem, but server rejects you query.

Comment: No, php-cli use php.ini like the navigator, the problem is not here. And it's not a reject by the server, it have no logs. I find the soluce, I don't know why but curl is blocked by SElinux when I use it from local to remote. I disabled SElinux and it's work. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you found the problem was SELinux, you can allow httpd to hit the network with `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on` and avoid disabling all of SELinux. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50808173/404960