# Apache cannot make outgoing HTTP Requests using curl

Tags: php, apache, curl, selinux, php-curl

Consider the following system configurations:

- Fedora 27
- SELinux enabled
- Apache/2.4.33
- PHP 7.1.17

And the below code snippet that is used to issue an http request to [Sphere-Engine Compilers API](https://developer.sphere-engine.com/api/compilers):

```
$ch = curl_init('http://xxxxxxxx.compilers.sphere-engine.com/api/v4/test?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3.0);
$x = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($x);
```

The above script works completely fine when I run the following CLI:

```
php script.php
```

And I get the intended output.

However, when I try to run it through the web browser it produces:

> CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT (7) Failed to connect() to host or proxy.

I have found many suggestions such as adding

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
```

Which wasn't really a solution for me. Turning off SELinux which I will **not** do.

**Note**: The URL itself is working fine when I issue it and gives me the intended output too.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: error is quite clear, can you run that url in a browser?

Comment: Yeah works completely fine.

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` add that and see if you get anything usefull

Comment: Nothing actually.

Comment: Can you connect to other URLs using `curl` from the webserver?

Comment: @Barmar Nope, I can't. [ Through the web browser ]

Comment: Then it sounds like an issue with the `php.ini` for the webserver has `curl` disabled. Or maybe SELinux has the webserver sandboxed so it can't make outgoing HTTP requests.

Comment: But if it's the SELinux case, wouldn't apache report something to the `error_log`, which shows nothing that helps?

Comment: Same problem here, Fedora 29, couldn't find an error anywhere until I looked in `/var/log/messages`:
`audit[2320]: AVC avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=2320 comm="php-fpm" dest=80 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:http_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket permissive=0`
and I wouldn't have remembered SELinux otherwise

Comment: Great you checked that file tho!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this to see if SELinux will let the web server connect to the network:

> getsebool httpd_can_network_connect

If not, allow it with

> setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-managing_confined_services-the_apache_http_server-booleans

Comment: Thank you very much.  This was the needle in the haystack I spent hours looking for.